# Vector Tiles in Openlayers 3

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, tiles, vector-tiles, tile-server

I am struggling to understand how to render vector tiles in Openlayers 3. this is probably due to me not understanding Z/X/Y tiles.

I have created an mbtile source and am serving it using tileserver-gl-light from a geojson data source using the EPSG:4326 projection.

```
tileserver-gl-light tiles.mbtiles
```

Works fine when I view them at (tileserver-gl-client):-

```
https://server:8080
```

And I get a tile downloaded with:-

```
http://server:8080/data/tiles/0/0/0.pbf
```

How can I now display this layer in openlayers? I have looked at the example [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html) but there is no mention of projection. I tried the following code

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
            format: new ol.format.MVT(),
            tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 22}),
            url: 'http://SERVER:8080/data/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
        })
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [125,83],
      zoom: 8
    })
  });
```

But have no idea how to centre it to the area I want  which is -4.2376,52.0528 Zoom level 8 in EPSG:4326

When I zoom or pan I get errors like:-

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/data/sn_all/8/128/123.pbf 404 (Not Found)
GET http://80.229.34.247:8080/data/sn_all/8/129/123.pbf 404 (Not Found)
```

Which makes me think my projection is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete example of using vector tiles hosted by TileServerGL (from MBTiles) in OpenLayers viewer is prepared here:

https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/openlayers3/

Technically, the default projection of the tiles inside the MBTiles is Mercator EPSG:3857.

For demo of different viewers of OpenMapTiles see
https://openmaptiles.org/viewers/