# Showing offline map downloaded from openmaptiles.com with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, mbtiles, localhost

I've downloaded .mbtiles file from https://openmaptiles.com/downloads and want to show the map in localhost. I've used following code but it did not show anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Local Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<a href="#mapDiv">Go to map</a>
<div id="mapDiv" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
<script>

var map;

function init() {
    map = new ol.Map ({
        target: 'mapDiv' });

    var newLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
            url: 'http://localhost/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.png'

                }) 
    });

    map.addLayer(newLayer);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following scenarios were tested and non of them were successful

- putting .mbtiles file and referring to it as `url: 'pathtofolder/file.mbtiles'`
- putting .mbtiles file and referring to its parent folder as `url: 'pathtoparentfolder'`
- extracting .mbtiles with mbutil and obtaining many many numbered folders with metadata.json file and referring to it as `url: 'pathtoparentfolder'`
- extracting .mbtiles with mbutil and obtaining many many numbered folders with metadata.json file and referring to it as `url: 'pathtoparentfolder/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'`

What is the problem and how can I debug OpenLayers? In fact I hesitate between using `ol.source.OSM` and `ol.source.XYZ`.

It's noteworthy to mention I have many .png files extracted in that folders but they can not be displayed.

Comment: Are you accessing the OpenLayers map via `http://localhost` too? Any errors in your Javascript console, "file not found" or similar?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225615/how-to-use-mapbox-vector-tiles-as-a-vector-source-in-ol3-so-that-labelling-will and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225339/vector-tiles-in-openlayers-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapbox-gl-js server offline example](https://github.com/klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example) that has a good example to do this.

Answer (score 6):

First, the .mbtiles files are not served directly to the browser. You'll need a WMS server that understands mbtiles format like Geoserver, which is made by Boundless, who is a major contributor to Openlayers, and also a former employer. If that WMS Server bit doesn't make sense to you, let's focus on serving up those PNGs.

So this bit of code-

```
source: new ol.source.OSM({
    url: 'http://localhost/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.png'
 })
```

is sort of doomed from the getgo. As you've noted, there are different types of sources in Openlayers, one of which is OSM (which is OpenStreetMap). That source is made specifically for serving tiles from OpenStreetMap servers, which you are not using. Let's forget that `ol.source.OSM` exists for now, because it's of no use to us.

What we need is a source that works for our use-case. As you said, your data is stashed in XYZ format on your hard drive. Let's let Openlayers know that:

```
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://localhost/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.png'
 })
```

Now, in order for this to work, you need to have a folder structure that looks like

`/path/to/webroot
|--map
    |--0 (folder)
       |--1 (folder)
       |  |--1.png
       |--2 (folder)
          |--1.png
    |--1 (folder)
       |--1 (folder)
       |  |--1.png
       |  |--2.png
       |--2 (folder)
          |--1.png
          |--2.png`

And so on. You can check your folder structure by pointing your web browser to `http://localhost/map/0/1/1.png`, for example.

Let's start there. Try using `ol.source.XYZ` - just change that one line and nothing else - and if that doesn't work, try going to the URL in the previous paragraph and see if that works.

Comment: The requested website offers vector mbtiles, not png files.

Comment: Thanks @onwsk8r. I've tested tileserver-php. Is it kind of WMS server?

Answer (score 1):

you need a vector tile server try https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl
As well as style

Also mbutil extracts mbtiles but the PBF are gzipped. And it does not unzip them

Comment: I've got tileserver-gl by npm but when I type `tileserver-gl country.mbtiles` it says command not found.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @GeospatialInformationTech TileServer would you be the best solution for your requirement.

Try the answer to 
[Tileserver-gl getting started procedure](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254920/tileserver-gl-getting-started-procedure) for your 'command not found' issue

Answer (score 0):

You can natively read vector tiles with openlayers 4. Use MBTILES.is or something similar to connect directly to your vector PBF tiles