# Tileserver-gl getting started procedure

Tags: mbtiles, server

I've followed instructions in [tileserver-gl github](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl) page and successfully install tileservre-gl, I mean `npm` command finished without error and all packages were downloaded.

`zurich_switzerland` file is also downloaded.

But when according to instructions I run `tileserver-gl zurich_switzerland.mbtiles` it says:

command not found.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was too facing similar issue, ensure that the command to run is

`npm install -g tileserver-gl-light` don't forget the `-g`

Do ensure to start Command Prompt as Administrator (Run as Administrator)

once the installation is finished check your 'npm' folder (in Windows it should in C:\Users\Your-User-Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules) for a folder named 'tileserver-gl-light'